# Redirecting old joomla 1.5 no SEF urls to new 2.5 SEF url before index.php strip

Tags: redirect, joomla, url-rewriting, sef

Im working in a new 2.5 joomla site and the old site was 1.5, the urls from the old site are no SEF. I need to redirect the old 1.5 no SEF urls to the new SEF urls, im doing this:

```
redirect 301 /index.php?option=com_k2&v... http://www.newsite.com/es
```

(Note the language in the url, its seem to be important for the problem, im using the joomla integrated language system)

But its not working, somehow joomla strips the index.php and the redirect doesnt work. I try to strip the index.php from the redirect, buts its doesnt work either. Im a noob in htaccess and redirects and im stuck in this... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, like this seems to be a hard problem, i think i just found a solution doing extensives testing and googling...

I found a rewrite and put it before the joomla rewrites:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)lang=es$
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /es? [R=301,L]
```

This replace the normal redirect 301.

Its hard for me to explain because i dont have too much knowledge about redirections and htaccess, the important think is that it seems to work for my problem, i hope other people just found this helpful.

If someone can explain the sintaxis of this code it will be grate.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is perform a complete redirect (without the query parameter i.e Redirect 301 / http://newsite.com/) and handle the query term on your new site with an SH404sef extension. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef/10134